# laravel delete method not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I've made a small  laravel project but the delete method is nog working:

I use a resource controller
my route is :

```
Route::resource('roles','Admin\RoleController');
```

in my view I have

```
 <form action="{{route('roles.destroy',$role->id)}}" style="display:inline">
    @method('delete')
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
 </form>
```

But when i click the button it will show me the role ( = get method of the resource )
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Laravel's [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#form-method-spoofing).
Did you try adding `method="POST"` to the form?

Comment: This was it. You have also must add a post method to the form it self thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you're using **Laravel 5.1** or later

```
<form action="{{ route('roles.destroy', 'YOUR_ID') }}" method="POST">
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
</form>
```

If you're using **Laravel 5.6** or later

```
<form action="{{ route('roles.destroy', 'YOUR_ID') }}" method="POST">
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
</form>
```

You can read more about method spoofing in Laravel Documentation.

Answer (score -1):

1. Check if form building is okay. And you are not using delete form inside an other form.
2. Check if delete route name exists in route file & you are using proper named routes.